# Compile code using bluez gatt api

Tags: c, linux, compilation, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am currently implementing a **BLE** server using `GATT` api from `bluez5` in C. I need to use my own service with custom characteristics.

Problem is that `bluez5` does not install all header of `GATT` api. Same problem in `libbluetooth` with does not provide all external `GATT`api.

Am I using the wrong api ? What is the tips to compile my code ?
Current dirty solution is to replace `btgatt-server.c` in tools directory of `bluez` source by my own code to be able to `dev/test` my implementation.

EDIT : 
I am using the last stable version of `bluez` : `5.32`

headers from `bluez` that I need to compile my code :

```
#include "lib/bluetooth.h"
#include "lib/hci.h"
#include "lib/hci_lib.h"
#include "lib/l2cap.h"
#include "lib/uuid.h"

#include "src/shared/mainloop.h"
#include "src/shared/util.h"
#include "src/shared/att.h"
#include "src/shared/queue.h"
#include "src/shared/timeout.h"
#include "src/shared/gatt-db.h"
#include "src/shared/gatt-server.h"
```

functions :

```
[arthur ] make 2>&1 | grep gatt_ | grep implicit
tools/btgatt-server.c:32:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gatt_db_attribute_read_result’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:60:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gatt_db_add_service’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:67:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gatt_db_service_add_characteristic’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:94:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gatt_db_service_set_active’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:110:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘bt_gatt_server_unref’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:111:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gatt_db_unref’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:186:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gatt_db_new’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:192:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘bt_gatt_server_new’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
tools/btgatt-server.c:202:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘bt_gatt_server_set_debug’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

These includes are not install by the Makefile of `bluez` on my system. And the library file does not include the function that I need either.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Bluez? Please supply this information.  Also have you tried http://www.bluez.org/ for assistance?

Comment: Also please supply the errors you are having? I would add more information, this really helps people that are trying to help you.

Comment: Out of interest, what version of kernel do you have -  is it at least the 2.4.6 release?

Comment: Sorry, full of options, but have you tried checking out the source and building that? Also have you tried to see if you can get a binary package of Bluez for your system and install that?

Comment: kernel 3.13.X. What do you mean by a binary package ? Bluez installation process provide library and headers files. So I am currently able to compile my code inside bluez sources but not outside.

Comment: sorry I've been trying to search for your problem - The binary reference was http://www.bluez.org/download/ - but this depends on your favour of linux. I would suggest posting your concerns on a related forum and seeing what others have to say. I also would trying as a super user if you aren't already.

Comment: I will try to get some help on bluez mailing list. Thanks Neil.

Comment: Those are internal bluez files. What you are trying to do is not officially supported (AFAIK).  Officially I believe you are supposed to use the DBUS APIs. In particular the new [gatt dbus apis](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt).

Comment: damn :( No other public API inside bluez ?. I am not a big fan of dbus

Comment: The official stance is to use DBUS, but it's limited (so I've been told) if you aren't using official BLE profiles.  The alternative is to make calls directly to the kernel in the same way the `gatttool` does.

Comment: @TimTisdall It's crazy that there is no clear API for a so common stuff like Bluetooth Low Energy. By the way not sure about the gatttool. This tool can only access service, but cannot create new one.

Comment: @ArthurLambert - sorry, I didn't read your question very closely...  I was also told that the shared library was not installed by default with `make install`.  I'm not sure if it includes those gatt_server components or what, though.  Bluez is really pushing everyone to use DBUS so I think they try to discourage use of the shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I will probably used `dbus` API later. But right now I am always using low c API from `bluez5` (path of example from bluez5 : bluez5_utils-5.31/tools/btgatt-server.c). To compile this standalone code outside bluez5 source directory I am using some include/library from bluez5 :

- libshared-mainloop.a
- libbluetooth-internal.a

In my case I am working with buildroot. So I add some piece of code in bluez5 mk file to get this missing library :

```
define BLUEZ5_UTILS_EXTERNALIZE_GATT
    mkdir -p $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/bluez5/gatt
    cp $(BLUEZ5_UTILS_SRCDIR)/src/uuid-helper.o $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/bluez5/gatt/.
    cp $(BLUEZ5_UTILS_SRCDIR)/src/.libs/libshared-mainloop.a $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/bluez5/gatt/.
    cp $(BLUEZ5_UTILS_SRCDIR)/lib/.libs/libbluetooth-internal.a $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/bluez5/gatt/.

    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/tools/btmgmt $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/bin/btmgmt
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/tools/btmgmt $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin/btmgmt
endef
```

Then in my Makefile I just need to link with these libraries + add -I to find missing header file which are in bluez5 source directory :

```
# find bluez5 header
HEADER += -I$(BLUEZ_PATH)

# link bluez5 libraries
BLUEZ5_LIB = $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/bluez5/gatt/libshared-mainloop.a BLUEZ5_LIB += $(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/bluez5/gatt/libbluetooth-internal.a
```

Anyway this is probably not the best way to do it but it is working great. Moreover `you don't need to do anything if you upgrade your bluez5 version`. I find some other solution like fork bluez5 and put some modification in Makefile to build a static library which contain all stuff that I need. But this solution is really painfully and you need to update your work at each new bluez5 release.

Comment: Thanks alot, Arthur! For the record, you don't even need to modify the bluez makefile, you can just link the static libraries directly from where they are after building bluez.